# Database-driven routing in Rails 3

Tags: ruby, database, ruby-on-rails-3, caching, routes

I'd like to ask a theoretical question about routing and using a database to look up specific routes.

Let's say that I have a product system. I know all about `to_param` and how it works ([thanks to Ryan Bates](http://railscasts.com/episodes/63-model-name-in-url) about a zillion years ago) and even that I can take the ID out of the param if I set it statically on the model itself.

The problem is that I want to take the ID out of it for search engine optimization and other purposes. I can't put it on the `Product` model itself, because the slug has the tendency to change with product changes, etc. Therefore, I need to keep slugs in something, e.g. a `Route` model. I have a table with a product_id column, and a slug column. The slug is indexed, so it would be fast for Rails to look up.

I have a few concerns, though:

1. Is this even the best way to do this?
2. Is there a way to cache the slugs in memory so that there isn't a roundtrip to the database every time?
3. Will my database take a huge hit if it is just looking up a simple slug in a table which is indexed? I suppose I will need to do some performance testing on this myself, but I am curious as to whether anyone else has ever measured this before.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Use http://memcached.org/

> Free & open source, high-performance, distributed memory object caching system, generic in nature, but intended for use in speeding up dynamic web applications by alleviating database load.
>
> Memcached is an in-memory key-value store for small chunks of arbitrary data (strings, objects) from results of database calls, API calls, or page rendering.
>
> Memcached is simple yet powerful. Its simple design promotes quick deployment, ease of development, and solves many problems facing large data caches. Its API is available for most popular languages.

Ruby gem is http://rubygems.org/gems/memcache

You may opt any gem here http://rubygems.org/searchutf8=%E2%9C%93&query=memcache

Comment: Yeah I am actually about to switch the entire database to Redis, so that may work, too. Thanks.